# Mask credit card number in PHP

Tags: php

I have credit card number which I want to mask as below:

```
$cc = 1234123412341234

echo cc_masking($cc)

1234XXXXXXXX1234

function cc_masking($number) {.....}
```

Please suggest the regular expression for this.

Comment: Fawad, just so you know, questions like this are discouraged on Stack Overflow. Readers overwhelmingly like to see questions that have actually been tried, or at least where a good deal of research effort has been made.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This should work using `substr`:

```
function ccMasking($number, $maskingCharacter = 'X') {
    return substr($number, 0, 4) . str_repeat($maskingCharacter, strlen($number) - 8) . substr($number, -4);
}
```

Comment: But American Express cards have 15 digits. What should I do then?

Comment: @fawad The new code should work - it will take the first 4 numbers, then input X's to match the length of the string - 8, and then add the last 4 numbers.

Answer (score 26):

You can use `substr_replace`

```
$var = '1234123412341234';
$var = substr_replace($var, str_repeat("X", 8), 4, 8);
echo $var;
```

Output

```
1234XXXXXXXX1234
```

Comment: very simple and handy

Answer (score 12):

```
<?php
echo 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-'.substr($cc,-4);
?>
```

Comment: Good point, it's much more standard to show the last four digits (though I suppose 15-digit chars should be catered for in the X's).

Comment: Simple. Awesome

Answer (score 4):

My 5 cents.

Examples:
371449635398431 => XXX-XXXX-XXXX-8431
4111111111111111 => XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1111

```
public function maskCreditCardNumber($cc, $maskFrom = 0, $maskTo = 4, $maskChar = 'X', $maskSpacer = '-')
{
    // Clean out
    $cc       = str_replace(array('-', ' '), '', $cc);
    $ccLength = strlen($cc);

    // Mask CC number
    if (empty($maskFrom) && $maskTo == $ccLength) {
        $cc = str_repeat($maskChar, $ccLength);
    } else {
        $cc = substr($cc, 0, $maskFrom) . str_repeat($maskChar, $ccLength - $maskFrom - $maskTo) . substr($cc, -1 * $maskTo);
    }

    // Format
    if ($ccLength > 4) {
        $newCreditCard = substr($cc, -4);
        for ($i = $ccLength - 5; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            // If on the fourth character add the mask char
            if ((($i + 1) - $ccLength) % 4 == 0) {
                $newCreditCard = $maskSpacer . $newCreditCard;
            }

            // Add the current character to the new credit card
            $newCreditCard = $cc[$i] . $newCreditCard;
        }
    } else {
        $newCreditCard = $cc;
    }

    return $newCreditCard;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your  function, if have only four digits like 1234 => xxxx is not working, please check it once and update please

Comment: The main idea was to mask the credit card number. The length of the CC number can be not less than 12 chars - check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number). In your case you can call `...->maskCreditCardNumber('1234', 1, 1)` and the result will be `1XX4`

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but here i want all four digit number should be mask XXXX, because it is four digits only

Comment: Ok, updated the code. you can call it as `...->maskCreditCardNumber('1234', 0, 4)` and you'll have the expected result. A third param can be `strlen($str)`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that:

- Credit card numbers might be contained in a bigger string containing more content
- All major credit cards are sum-checked using the Luhn algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

This is what I do:

- I detect, via regex, if a string contains a chain of digits, separated or not by spaces and hyphens.
- For every match, I strip it from non-numeric values and check if is a valid Luhn.
- Replace the part I want, for every match, with replacement characters (usually "*").

The code is this:

```
public function mask($string)
{
    $regex = '/(?:\d[ \t-]*?){13,19}/m';

    $matches = [];

    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

    // No credit card found
    if (!isset($matches[0]) || empty($matches[0]))
    {
        return $string;
    }

    foreach ($matches as $match_group)
    {
        foreach ($match_group as $match)
        {
            $stripped_match = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $match);

            // Is it a valid Luhn one?
            if (false === $this->_util_luhn->isLuhn($stripped_match))
            {
                continue;
            }

            $card_length = strlen($stripped_match);
            $replacement = str_pad('', $card_length - 4, $this->_replacement) . substr($stripped_match, -4);

            // If so, replace the match
            $string = str_replace($match, $replacement, $string);
        }
    }

    return $string;
}
```

You will see a call to $this->_util_luhn->isLuhn, which is a function that does this:

```
public function isLuhn($input)
{

    if (!is_numeric($input))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $numeric_string = (string) preg_replace('/\D/', '', $input);

    $sum = 0;

    $numDigits = strlen($numeric_string) - 1;

    $parity = $numDigits % 2;

    for ($i = $numDigits; $i >= 0; $i--)
    {
        $digit = substr($numeric_string, $i, 1);

        if (!$parity == ($i % 2))
        {
            $digit <<= 1;
        }

        $digit = ($digit > 9)
            ? ($digit - 9)
            : $digit;

        $sum += $digit;
    }

    return (0 == ($sum % 10));
}
```

It is how I implemented it in https://github.com/pachico/magoo/.
Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to show only last 4 digits, here is a dynamic way. Works with both credit cards, ACH numbers or anything:

https://gist.github.com/khoipro/815ea292e2e87e10771474dc2ef401ef

```
    $variable = '123123123';
    $length = strlen($variable);
    $output = substr_replace($variable, str_repeat('X', $length - 4), 0, $length - 4);
    echo $output;
```

Comment: I've add this answer because i'm searching for that solution. Hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 2):

```
str_pad(substr($value,-4),strlen($value), "X", STR_PAD_LEFT); //output: XXXXXXXXXXXX9494
```

Answer (score 1):

With regular expression

```
function cc_masking( $number, $maskChar = 'X' ) {
    return preg_replace(
        '/^(....).*(....)$/',
        '\1' . str_repeat( $maskChar, strlen( $number ) - 8) . '\2',
        $number );
}
```

You keep the first four characters (and the last four), replacing the others with X.

Answer (score 0):

No need for regular expression for this. Just take n numbers at the beginning, n numbers at the end then add the X in the middle to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Not the elegant way but it works

```
<?php
     $cc = "1234123412341234";
     function cc_masking($number) {
     $int_first = 4;
     $int_last = 4;
     $chars = strlen($number);
     $repeater = "x";
     $repeates = $chars-$int_first-$int_last;
     // echo "<p>Org: $number</p>";
     $mask = substr($number,0,4).str_repeat($repeater,$repeates).substr($cc,-4);
     // echo "<p>Mask: $mask";
         return $mask;
      }
     echo cc_masking($cc);
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for some code similar. So I found the code below. I hope can help.

```
function mask($val, $mask)
{
    $maskared = '';

    $k = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($mask) - 1; $i++) {
        if ($mask[$i] == '#') {
            if (isset($val[$k]))
                $maskared .= $val[$k++];
        } else {
            if (isset($mask[$i]))
                $maskared .= $mask[$i];
        }
    }

    return $maskared;
}
```

Sample:

```
echo mask(11111111111, "###.###.###-##"); // 111.111.111-11
echo mask(11111111111, "#####-###"); // 111111-111
echo mask(11111111111, anything); // 111111-111
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer in this question is made from @h2ooooooo, but the code will return error if the result of strlen($number)-8 will be less than 0. So you only have to create a control if else to avoid this, also I have add some other features.

```
 function maskNumbers($number) {

    $start=4;
    
    $end=4;
    $char="*";// or X, x ,+ whatever you like

    $repeat_length=$start+$end; 

    if((strlen($number)-$repeat_length)>0){

        return substr($number, 0, $start) . str_repeat($maskingCharacter, strlen($number)-$repeat_length) . substr($number, -($end));

    }else {
        return $number; //Will return the wrong length phone numbers, cards numbers  as  they are
    }  
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$accNum = "1234123412341234";

$accNum1 = substr($accNum,2,2);

$accNum1 = '**'.$accNum1;

$accNum2 = substr($accNum,6,100);

$accNum2 = '**'.$accNum2;

$accNum = $accNum1.$accNum2;

echo $accNum;
```

Comment: That results in `**34**3412341234`, which doesn't match the mask in the question.