# How to hide digits from numbers

Tags: php

I have a contact number in a variable and i want to hide sum digits in php.

like:-

`$contact=9899784414`;

```
$email= 'divakar.kumar6@gmail.com';
```

expected result: `98XXXXXX14`

```
divaxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
```

Comment: And where is the problem?

Comment: So what have you tried? HINT: A string in PHP is also an array of characters

Comment: Are you looking for such solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413886/mask-credit-card-number-in-php

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$email = 'divakar.kumar6@gmail.com';
$email =  substr_replace($email,"xxxxxxxxxx",3,10);

$contact = "9899784414";
$contact = substr_replace($contact,"xxxxxx",2,6);

echo $email;
echo "<br/>";
echo $contact;
```

Comment: How could you put static nos like 3 and 10? And 2 and 6? For email, if it's some other id like example@gmail.com, it will produce undesired result.

Comment: Now how would someone replace before reaching the @ value. Your answer will only apply to domains with length of ten from the @value like gmail. how can you go about that?

Comment: @ObjectManipulator ith hide the position from 3 from 10 for emails and characters 2 to 6 for phone number

Comment: @OmariOmosa the objective of the op to hide the email id

Comment: @VinodVT lets say the emails are dynamically generated and can be of different lengths. i.e. `blabla@gmail.com` ,`blabla@facebook.com` These emails have different lengths from the @ value