# Replacing First 4 digits of a 10 digit number with x

Tags: php

I'm trying to replace the first 4 digits of a number with X, for example:

```
$num= 1234567890
```

I want the output to appear like this: XXXX567890

I have tried the function:

```
 $new = substr($num, 0, -4) . 'xxx';
```

but It only removes the last 4 digits so what should I do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mask credit card number in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413886/mask-credit-card-number-in-php)

Comment: Is the number a fixed length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `substr_replace` function:

```
$num = 1234567890;
print_r(substr_replace($num, 'XXXX', 0, 4));    // XXXX567890
```

Comment: That's a good answer. Never thought about `substr_replace`. I think I need to update my function.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the same in opposite

```
$num= 1234567890;
$new = 'xxxx' . substr($num, 4);
echo $new;
```

second parameter tells about starting point for string and parity(positive or negative) tells about direction. positive number means to right of string and negative number means to left of string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1):

I think this one can be helpful for achieving desired output.

**Solution 1:**
[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/862929)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$num= 1234567890;
echo "XXXX".substr($num, 4);//concatenating 4 X and with the substring
```

**Solution 2:** [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/862933)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$num= 1234567890;
$totalDigits=4;
echo str_repeat("X", $totalDigits).substr($num, $totalDigits);// here we are using str_repeat to repeat a substring no. of times
```

**Output:** `XXXX567890`

Comment: Why _should_ they do it like that, considering there is a native function `substr_replace`?

Comment: @Progrock I have given two solution `1.` Correction of OP code. `2.` is something dynamic there will be no need to provide that no. of `X`explicitly, If you change `$totalDigits` to 3 it will work dynamically for 3 as well.

Comment: @Progrock I don't think it's a matter of what should be done. It's a matter of what OP likes. Sometimes it's not what we may think is a good solution that the OP likes.

Comment: @Progrock yaah you are right. I tried myself to give the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use str_pad which "fills up" the string to 10 elements with "X".

```
$num= 1234567890;

Echo str_pad(substr($num,4), 10, "X",STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

https://3v4l.org/tKtB7

Or if the string lenght is not always 10 use:

```
Echo str_pad(substr($num,4), strlen($num), "X",STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

If have written a tiny function to do tasks like this.

```
function hide_details($str, $num = 4, $replace = 'x') {
    return str_repeat($replace, $num).substr($str, $num);
}
echo hide_details('1234567890');
```