# How to update the value with some other symbol in php?

Tags: php

I have one field card number , when ever I hit the api it's displaying all the 16digits of a card, I want to show first 5digits and last 4digits , remaining digits should be replaced by * symbol, is there any way to acheive this thing by using php functions.

```
$card=12345678901234567 //card_number from databse.

Expected result is
$card=12345******34567
```

Comment: $card = substr($card, 0, 5) . '******' . substr($card, -5, 5);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mask credit card number in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413886/mask-credit-card-number-in-php)

Comment: Thanks it's working fine